# How to map JsonList to a Java Object List Efficiently?

Tags: java, json, spring, jackson

I am using Jackson to map the following Json List to a Java Object List.

So below is the list.

```
 String UserListString="[{\"UID\":1,\"Username\":\"111\",\"ID\":\"rey\",\"Name\":\"User01\",\"Date\":\"12-10-2016 10:07\",\"ItemList\":[{\"Item\":9,\"Code\":\"dggd\"}]},{\"UID\":2,\"Username\":\"222\",\"ID\":\"dsse\",\"Name\":\"User02\",\"Date\":\"13-10-2016 02:08\",\"ItemList\":[{\"Item\":4,\"Code\":\"res\"}]},{\"UID\":3,\"Username\":\"333\",\"ID\":\"wee\",\"Name\":\"User03\",\"Date\":\"13-10-2016 02:09\",\"ItemList\":[{\"Item\":1,\"Code\":\"ret\"}]";
```

I parse this by below:

```
 ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();   
 ArrayList<Users> list =new ArrayList<Users> ();
 list = objectMapper.readValue(UserListString,TypeFactory.defaultInstance().constructCollectionType((Class<? extends Collection>) List.class,  Users.class));
```

My Users class is below:

```
public class Users {

    @JsonProperty("UID")
    private String UID;

    @JsonProperty("Username")
    private String Username;


    @JsonProperty("ID")
    private String ID;

    @JsonProperty("Name")
    private String Name;

    @JsonProperty("Date")
    private String Date;



    @JsonProperty("ItemList")
    private ArrayList<Item>ItemList;

..///getters and setters
}
```

My Item class

```
public class Item {
    private String Item;
    private String Code;
    public String getItem() {
        return Item;
    }
    public void setItem(String item) {
        Item = item;
    }
    public String getCode() {
        return Code;
    }
    public void setCode(String code) {
        Code = code;
    }



}
```

The error I receive is like

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not create TypeBindings for class java.awt.List with 1 type parameter: class expects 0
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

At a minimum, you need to change this import:

```
import java.awt.List;
```

...to

```
import java.util.List;
```

the one you currently have in there relates to the [Abstract Window Toolkit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_Window_Toolkit), not the Java collection interface.